# How to use limit and offet in get http request?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have GET request with parameters: `offset: <number>` and `limit: <number>` also parameter `sortB`y that accepts fiels devided by comma.

How to describe get method better?

```
getData(limit: number, offset: number, sortBy?: string) {
    return this.http.get("");
}


interface Request {
   limit: number;
   offset: number;
   sortBy: string;
}

getData(request: Request) {
    return this.http.get("");
}
```

Or this:

```
interface Request {
   limit: number;
   offset: number;
   sortBy: string[];
}

getData(request: Request) {
    const sortBy = request.split(",");
    return this.http.get("");
}
```

Comment: Can you add more information what you exactly looking for?

Comment: I dont know how to pass parameters limit, offset correctly to http.get() request, using interface or literal parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is only being passed in Get request in the form of either `params`/`query params` or by adding into the `headers` of request.

In your case, your get request endpoints need to define how backend endpoint code accepting the data whether in the form of parameters or in the form of query params.

Also instead of declaring an interface you could just construct a query string and append at the end of endpoint like mentioned below -

```
getData(limit: number, offset: number, sortBy?: string) {
    let params = `?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}&sortBy=${sortBy}`
    return this.http.get("https://yourendpoint.com" + params);
}
```

Here sortBy you may further manipulate by comma basis as per need.

## Update - call another HTTP call on the first request complete

```
this.http.get("https://yourendpoint.com" + params);.subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    // Next call here
});
```

Comment: What is benefit of using `   const params = new HttpParams()` instead inline style?

Comment: by using `new HttpParams()` its easier to maintain a large piece of code and its a recommended way to of doing this as per the documentation, but In case of sending only one or two params I usually prefer as posted in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I will accept you answers, also could you explain how to execute next request when previous request returns link url to the next, prev page? Should I create sepearet class like NextPrevPage {} and two methods in service: next(), prev()?

Comment: You can call the next call in the success method callback of first request (by calling another generic function)

Comment: Could you share an sampl please?

Comment: So, I need request next page from prev response: `getOrders(
    offset: number,
    limit: number,
    sortby: string[]
  ): Observable<Response> {}`

Comment: could you ask different question stating all the information you have and you want?

Comment: Yes, but I dont have enouth rating, it is bloked me for some reasons

Comment: @Den please check my updated answer

Comment: I got you, I meant I have a new URL string of next page and prev page. And I need call it after click buttion next. Should I write class for it or just add methods getNextPage() getPrevPage() in service Angular? and add here property nextPage: string; prevPage: string?

Comment: I believe you don't need to add more class, just new function can do trick for you got for it :)